# how to test if the apt cache is up to date with bash

Tags: apt, bash, scripts

I'm searching a way to test in a bash script if a cache update is needed (to avoid unnecessary `apt-get update` when the apt-cache have been updated recently).

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as  [Tuomas](https://serverfault.com/users/135079/tuomas) [found out on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/20747/), there's an `APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success` invocation pinged off by default in Ubuntu. It touches another file when an update finishes successfully. It shouldn't trigger when installing things.

You can check it like this:

```
$ stat -c %z /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
2014-06-24 12:58:52.414894266 +0100
```

`stat` supports a load of different output formats (see `man stat` if you need another) so that should be good for most purposes.

Comment: Thank you. I'll probably use the `-c %Z flag`, as I need the epoch time for my script.